I need help obtaining the total number of pages in Microsoft Word
I have developed a C++ console application that utilizes Microsoft COM (Component Object Model) to interface with Microsoft Word. The primary goal of this application is to retrieve and display the total number of pages in the currently active Word document. This feature is crucial as it allows users to quickly assess the length of their documents without manually checking Word.
Despite having active documents open in Microsoft Word while executing my application, I am encountering a persistent issue: the application consistently returns a page count of 0. This behavior is unexpected, as I have verified that there are indeed documents currently open and visible in Word.
To troubleshoot this problem, I have carefully reviewed my code to ensure that I am correctly initializing the COM library, creating instances of the Word application, and accessing the active document. However, I am still unable to obtain the correct page count.
I am particularly concerned that there may be an issue with how I am accessing the document properties or perhaps how I am interacting with the Word application through COM. It is also important to ascertain whether I am using the correct methods and properties to retrieve the page count reliably.
Below, I have attached the relevant source code for review. I would greatly appreciate any assistance or insights you can provide to help me troubleshoot this problem effectively. Your expertise would be invaluable in identifying any potential issues in my code or suggesting alternative approaches to ensure I can successfully retrieve the total number of pages in the active Word document.
#include <iostream>
#include <comdef.h>
#include <comutil.h>

#import "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\MSWORD.OLB" \
    raw_interfaces_only \
    named_guids \
    exclude("IRawDispatchDriver") \
    rename("DocumentProperties", "WordDocumentProperties") \
    rename("RGB", "WordRGB") \
    rename("ExitWindows", "WordExitWindows")

using namespace Word;

int main() {
    // Initialize COM library
    CoInitialize(NULL);

    try {
        // Create Word application instance
        _ApplicationPtr pWordApp;
        HRESULT hr = pWordApp.CreateInstance(L"Word.Application");
        if (FAILED(hr)) {
            throw _com_error(hr);
        }

        // Make the application visible
        pWordApp->put_Visible(VARIANT_TRUE);

        // Retrieve the Documents collection
        DocumentsPtr pDocuments; // Correct pointer type
        hr = pWordApp->get_Documents(&pDocuments);
        if (FAILED(hr) || pDocuments == nullptr) {
            throw _com_error(hr);
        }

        // Get the count of documents
        long count;
        hr = pDocuments->get_Count(&count);
        if (FAILED(hr)) {
            throw _com_error(hr);
        }

        // Check if any documents are open
        if (count > 0) {
            _DocumentPtr pDoc; // Pointer to hold the active document
            hr = pWordApp->get_ActiveDocument(&pDoc.GetInterfacePtr()); // Use smart pointer interface
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && pDoc != nullptr) {
                // Successfully retrieved the active document
                pDoc->Activate(); // Activate the document

                // Get the number of pages
                VARIANT includeFootnotesAndEndnotes;
                VariantInit(&includeFootnotesAndEndnotes); // Initialize the variant
                includeFootnotesAndEndnotes.vt = VT_BOOL; // Set type to boolean
                includeFootnotesAndEndnotes.boolVal = VARIANT_FALSE; // Set the value to FALSE

                long numPages;
                hr = pDoc->ComputeStatistics(Word::wdStatisticPages, &includeFootnotesAndEndnotes, &numPages);
                if (FAILED(hr)) {
                    throw _com_error(hr);
                }

                std::wcout << L"Number of pages: " << numPages << std::endl;

                // Resources are released automatically by smart pointers
            }
            else {
                throw _com_error(hr);
            }
        }
        else {
            std::wcout << L"No document is currently open." << std::endl;
        }
    }
    catch (_com_error& e) {
        // Handle COM errors
        std::wcerr << L"COM Error: " << e.ErrorMessage() << std::endl;
    }

    // Uninitialize COM library
    CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}


"the total number of pages in the currently active Word document" - I don't see where you attach to the active Word application. The 0 is expected in these circumstances.

There is c++ code in this example code that obtains the active Excel instance which should be similar to Word: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/getobject-or-getactiveobject-cannot-find-a-running-office-application-6cdf21a3-ac90-512b-6bff-badc5f4cc215
